# How do I auto correct colors in an image?

Tags: image-processing, colors, signal-processing, histogram

I will work with a set of arbitrary images. 
Some of them might need some color correction.

I've opened up an image that needed correction in Photoshop
and noticed the yellows were a bit high in the Histogram.
I applied Auto Color and that improved the image.

How does that work ? How implement that ?
Do I look for peaks in the histogram and average them based on the 
other peaks ?

The language/syntax shouldn't matter much.

Comment: try this: http://discuss.fogcreek.com/joelonsoftware/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=35964

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't easy and it does take practice and art, but here's the theory.

Tools like Photoshop and Picasa have automatic color correction on one button. It has to make assumptions about what the mean color distributions ought be and they probably work in the Lab color space rather than the RGB colorspace that you are familiar with. Since the approach is heuristic, it will get it wrong for some images. For example, if you take images in a bright yet shrouded forest, the ambient light has a decided green cast and you simply cannot jiggle the colors to make a white object white because you'd have to push too hard into the red thus screwing up, for example, a green shirt. Similarly, images in from the late afternoon orange sun are yellow biased and to correct that pushes too hard into the blue. There may be stop values in the auto-color modes to avoid over compensation.

Now Lab colorspace is a strange beast and there are literally entire books about it. It is a three channel space with Luminance on one channel (that's the easy one) and channels that have so little connection to the way we think of color that they are simply called "a" and "b". The a and b channels encode all the chromaticity data (everything that isn't Luminance) in dimensions that could be roughly called yellow-blue and green-red. Here's another weirdness, the gamut of Lab is far bigger than our eyes can handle (RGB and CMYK are both smaller than our visual gamut) yielding colors that are impossible, for example a deeply saturated red with almost no Luminance. We can describe it, but our perception drops color out as Luminance decreases (which is why nighttime give everything a blue-grey appearance).

So how would you do so algorithmically? First, you need to really understand the perceptual models, transform the images into a perceptual space, adjust the bi-axial distribution according to pretty complicated expectations of normal and then cast the result back into an RGB space so it can be rendered. Yes, this can be implemented in a pocket camera, but it is non-trivial and often needs hints (e.g. setting the expected color temperature to sunny or shaded, tungsten, or fluorescent, etc.). Absent human guidance algorithms will be wrong more often, and without hand masking some color casts like the green forest can't be done pleasingly on an image as a whole.

tl;dr

Comment: A reference to Lab color space would be most welcome. I'm always reluctant to trust Wikipedia on technical topics (I've seen what happens to topics on which I have expertise).

Comment: If you are looking for a mostly intuitive photographer's guide, Margulis is probably the book to read http://www.amazon.com/Photoshop-LAB-Color-Adventures-Colorspace/dp/0321356780 If you are looking for a rigorous mathematical treatment, I'd send you to the CIE but there have to be better reads and I'd hit Wikipedia's bibliography (the hive mind treatment of color there has been accurate for my (non Lab) activities)

Comment: very informative, as far as I can understand I need to convert from RGB to L*a*b*(RGB to XYZ, XYZ to L*a*b*), do the adjustments in L*a*b* and after that, get the values back to RGB. I didn't understand which 'axis' when said 'bi-axial distribution'. La, Lb, ab ?

Comment: bi-axial is ab; changes to the L channel don't affect color at all (exceot by changing value or brightness). As the RGB ⇒ Lab ⇒ RGB is an isomorphic translation, you could conceivably do the same operations in RGB space, but the mathematics would be ummm... complicated.

Comment: cool. I understand now. And yes, although changing a and b in RGB would be possible, it would be error prone and not very practical.

Answer (score 1):

Simple algorithm could look like this:

- Calculate histogram (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram)
- Find lowest (a) and highest points (b) in histogram where values are less than 1% than highest value.
- Adjust brightness to center histogram. Multiply color values by 256/(a+b)
- Adjust contrast to spread histogram from 0 to 255. Multiply color values by 127/(bb-128), where bb is b multiplied by brightness value.

This is very simplistic algorithm but I think this is what happens in many programs. Additionally programs might do something about saturation.